# Using onChangeText and onFocus to alter style of a text block

Tags: javascript, react-native

Refering to the code below, how can I write it so that when onFocus and onChangeText is called, the value of marginTop changes from 3 to 5?

```
       <Block>
          <Text marginTop={3}>TEXT</Text>
          <Block>
            <Input
              keyboardType="phone-pad"
              placeholder="Phone number"
              defaultValue={details?.phone}
              onChangeText={(value) => onChange({ phone: value })}
              onFocus?
            />
          </Block>
        </Block>
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

margin changes when either `onChangeText`  or `onFocus` is called

```
 const [changeMargin, setChangeMargin] = useState(false)  ;
    <Block>
                  <Text marginTop={changeMargin ? 5: 3}>TEXT</Text>
                  <Block>
                    <Input
                      keyboardType="phone-pad"
                      placeholder="Phone number"
                      defaultValue={details?.phone}
                      onChangeText={(value) => { if(value !=null && value.length >0){setChangeMargin(true) ;}else{setChangeMargin(false) ;};
 onChange({ phone: value })}}
                      onFocus={()=>{setChangeMargin(true)}}
                    />
                  </Block>
                </Block>
```

Comment: Thanks @sandarshnaroju, this nearly what I'm looking for. But if the Input field is empty, marginTop still stays at 5. How can I change it so that if input is empty it will change back to 3?

Comment: @rbq10 made changes accordingly, once check.

Comment: Thanks again @sandarshnaroju. I tried applying what was written for onChangeText to onBlur, but it did not work. Do you know why?

Comment: are you trying to change the marginTop to 3 when onBlur calls?? If so, `onBlur={()=>{setChangeMargin(false)}}`

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying out to make it conditional, meaning for onBlur if value != null ..etc then setChangeMargin(true) ... else setChangeMargin(false)

Comment: onBlur callBack doesnt have a value param.

Comment: Ahhh... I guessed that. So how could it be written to consider the value changes?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [move, setMove] = useState(false)
<Block>
  <Text marginTop={3}>TEXT</Text>
  <Block>
    <Input
      keyboardType="phone-pad"
      placeholder="Phone number"
      defaultValue={details?.phone}
      onChangeText={(value) => setMove(true)
      style={move && /* do something*/}
      onFocus?
    />
  </Block>
</Block>
```